# How to use mask image in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I want to mask the UIImageView with mask image, like that:

```
let mask = UIImageView(image: MASKIMAGE)
profileImageView.mask = mask
```

But the black parts in mask image have to transparent.
[image]

How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve!

Now I can make non-white color to transparent.

```
let components: [CGFloat] = [0,254,0,254,0,254]
let alphaImage = UIImage(cgImage: (MASKIMAGE.cgImage?.copy(maskingColorComponents: components))!)
let mask = UIImageView(image: alphaImage)
profileImageView.mask = mask
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using **PNG** image for your `MASKIMAGE` with transparent pixels? Do not use JPEG for masks. The black area that you expect to be transparent should actually contain alpha channel value of 0.

```
R = Some value (122)
G = Some value (23)
B = Some value (33)
A = 0 for fully transparent area
```

---

If the image contains alpha values `1`, then you need to edit and re-add the image to your assets so that only the information that you need (mask shape) has alpha value of `1` and everything else `0`. You can do it in photoshop or any other image editing software.

Comment: Unfortunately, my png mask image has A=1. So, how can I deal with that? Thank you!

Comment: @13thang08 Then you need to edit the image and add it to your assets so that only the information that you need (mask shape) has alpha value of 1 and everything else 0. You can do it in photoshop or any other image editing software.